# Symmetrically extending a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I extend a matrix in MATLAB by symmetrically replicating the boundary values? For example, if `X` is my matrix, extended matrix `Xextsym` should look like the following:

```
X =
 1     2     3
 4     5     6 

Xextsym =
 5     4     4     5     6     6     5
 2     1     1     2     3     3     2
 2     1     1     2     3     3     2
 5     4     4     5     6     6     5
 5     4     4     5     6     6     5
 2     1     1     2     3     3     2
```

I'm aware that a function called [`wextend`](http://mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wextend.html) exists in the Wavelet Toolbox for this task exactly, but I don't have it.

Comment: You should precise by how many row/column you want to extend in each direction.

Comment: If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use [padarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html).

Comment: I can get the desired result with padarray as well:
`padarray(padarray(x,2,'symmetric','both')', 2,'symmetric','both')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that extends a given matrix A by symmetric reflection, adding w element in each of four directions. Usage example:

```
symextend([1 2 3; 4 5 6], 2)
```

returns the extended matrix in your question.

```
function R = symextend(A, w)
  [m, n] = size(A);
  B = [A A(:, n:-1:1); A(m:-1:1, :) A(m:-1:1, n:-1:1)];
  repm = 2*ceil(0.5+0.5*w/m);
  repn = 2*ceil(0.5+0.5*w/n);
  C = repmat(B, repm, repn);
  R = C(m*repm + 1 - w : m*repm + m + w, n*repn + 1 - w : n*repn + n + w)
end
```

Idea: first reflect A once in each direction (this produces B), then repeat B with `repmat`, obtaining C. Finally, a suitable piece is carved out of C. The tricky parts are counting how many times to repeat, and which part to carve out.